# Find a pdf of $Y= B X$ where $B\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a continuous random vector

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, linear-transformations

Is there a general formula for the pdf of $Y \in \mathbb{R}^m$ where
\begin{align}
Y= B X
\end{align}
where $B\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ has a pdf $f(x)$.

**Case $m=n$ and $B$ is invertible** For this case the solution is given by
\begin{align}
f_Y(y)= \frac{1}{|\det(B)|}  f( B^{-1} y).
\end{align}

My question is what can we say about the general case?